# Why does this work and how? Non-static Qt object

Tags: c++, qt, static, qt4

I'm a little confused and would like to clear this up.

```
//QDir()::rmdir is from Qt Creator auto complete.
//It does not work. 
//Says no such static function.I looked it up, turns out to be true.
//Fair enough...though I'm not sure why auto-complete suggested it.
bool success = QDir()::rmdir("Y:/dir1/dir2/dir3");   //Does not work.

//Now I could make a QDir object as such.
//I didn;t test this but I'm sure it would work fine.
//However it seems clumsy.
QDir d("Y:/");     //This seems like a waste.
d.rmdir("Y:/dir1/dir2/dir3");

//Lastly, the source of my confusion.  QDir().rmdir
//This works, but WHY?
//There is no empty constructor for QDir in Qt Documentation.
//http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdir.html
//Yet this empty constructor version works.  Why?
bool success = QDir().rmdir("Y:/dir1/dir2/dir3");
```

My main concern is why does the last examaple [QDir().rmdir] work?
I've noticed this on a number of Qt classes.  Is this an anonymous object and if so
what does this mean with regards to object clean up?  Is this form safe to use?

Comment: Do you mean `QDir::rmdir("Y:/dir1/dir2/dir3")`?  It still won't work because `QDir::rmdir` is not static, but the extra parentheses in `QDir()::rmdir` make no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the QDir constructors is:

```
QDir ( const QString & path = QString() )
```

Your QDir().xxx code is calling this constructor, which then uses default to using a QString() as one argument.

This is safe and normal to do.

Comment: Ahh, I should have looked closer at the doc.  I missed the =QString() default param.  With that cleared up, I take it that it would be better to use this "anonymous"/"temp" object style only in functions right?  Else it could take a long time to delete considering that I have no way to trigger the deletion of this nameless object.  What is the best practice approach to this?

Comment: @user440297: this anonymous object will be deleted at the end of the full-expression, i.e. at the `;`

Answer (score 0):

QDir creates a temporary object. Pretty the same if you callsth. like:

```
QString s("123"); 
int answer = 40 + s.left(2).right(1).toInt();
```

Second line produces 2 temporary objects.